# Gnome 3 Laptop Touchpad Middle Click not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME 3 Laptop Touchpad Click stopped working. Would highly appreciate if some one guide me how to fix this problem.

Thanks!

**Edited**

I tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true
```

but it throws the following error:

```
No such key 'middle-button-enabled'
```

Comment: Any solution @moo_we_all_do for the problem, please.

Comment: is your mouse's middle clicking working?

Comment: Thanks @Anwar for your comment. My Laptop Touchpad middle part stopped working after upgradation. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I'm not using touchpad. Don't know. You have to wait for some time for the solution to come