# Ubuntu 16.04. Synaptics touchpad features stop working

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, synaptics

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Touchpad features (two-finger scrolling, etc) suddenly stop working, maybe after last update. Touchpad tab is missing in **System -> Preferences -> Mouse**. My touchpad simply act like a mouse.

`synclient` output:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

`xinput list` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
...
```

`xinput list-props 12` output:

```
Device 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (263):    2, 1
    Device Node (264):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (277): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (279):  0
    Axis Labels (280):  "Rel X" (152), "Rel Y" (153)
    Button Labels (281):    "Button Left" (145), "Button Middle" (146), "Button Right" (147), "Button Wheel Up" (148), "Button Wheel Down" (149)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (282): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (283):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (284):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (285): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (286): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (287):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (288):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (289):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (290):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (291):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (292):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (293): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (294):  0
```

Already trying reinstall `xserver-xorg` and `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not only touchpad but also keyboard, even USB attached keyboard and mouse stopped working. http://askubuntu.com/q/819341/283472 and here http://askubuntu.com/q/820016/283472

Comment: Beware, don't update now (unfortunately I did). Otherwise your keyboard will stop working too http://askubuntu.com/q/820016/283472.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 16.04.  First thing I did was look for the synaptics config file in /etc/X11 but I don't see it anymore.  So I did this:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
cd /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf  .
```

That didn't really help any.  So that step might be totally unecessary.

After that I noticed something disabled my touchpad.  To fix, I did this:

```
synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

After rebooting this didn't seem to be a problem any more.

Comment: The first part fixed it for me.  Didn't have to do the `TouchPadOff=0` bit.  Thanks!