# Keyboard and Synaptics touchpad features stopped working after xenial software update

Tags: updates, keyboard, touchpad, synaptics

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 system this morning as follows:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

After a reboot, I found that the "hold-to-repeat" keyboard functionality stopped working for all keys. For example, holding `Backspace` deletes 1 to 5 letters and then stops instead of continuing to the key's release.

Also, basic functionality of my Synaptics touchpad suddenly disappeared, including "tap to click" and "two-finger scrolling."

Both of these features are enabled under system settings.

Could `apt autoremove` be responsible for this?

The situation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820005/ubuntu-16-04-synaptics-touchpad-features-stop-working) is the most similar, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the kernel, use an older version, clicking "**Esc**" at system boot and going to "**Advanced Options**" and then select the previous kernel.

(Sorry, my English is still bad).

Comment: Switching to an earlier kernel fixed it! I'll have to submit a bug report on this.

Comment: @cp289 Could you please provide the link to the bug, if you reported it :)

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Unfortunately, I switched to Arch Linux and the bug report expired a while ago.